# Jetpack Compose:composable that have too many composables can cause the lazyColumn get stuck when it scroll

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want a graph like this.

[image]

The graph is composable in LazyColumn's item. And the lazyColumn get stuck when the graph shows and hides. How to optimize it?

**code:**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun List(){
  LazyColumn(){
    item{
      Graph()
    }
    items{
      // other items
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun Graph(){
Row(Modifer.height(200.dp)) {
  // other simple Composables,
  if(isShow)
  repeat(30){
    Column() {
            repeat(7) {
                Box(Modifer.size(16.dp).background(Blue))
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know much about compose.I found a way to fixme it.
Use **Side-effect**.

```kotlin
@Composable

fun List(){
  val isShow = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
  val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    LaunchedEffect(listState) {
    // Graph is first item
        snapshotFlow { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }.collect {
            if (it != 0) {
                isShow.value = false
            }else{
                isShow.value = true
            }
        }
    }
  LazyColumn(state = listState){
    item{
      Graph(isShow.value)
    }
    items{
      // other items
    }
  }
}
@Composable
fun Graph(isShow:Boolean){
Row(Modifer.height(200.dp)) {
  // other simple Composables,
  if(isShow)
  repeat(30){
    Column() {
            repeat(7) {
                Box(Modifer.size(16.dp).background(Blue))
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

There are simple codes.
Is a good way?

Comment: Your view is not really lazy: `LazyColumn` reuses one of multiple items. You're placing the whole view inside one `item`, so it'll always be shown. You need to split your graph between multiple items. Also not sure how you expect to scroll it, maybe `LazyRow` will fit better here?

Comment: As to your question, it's unclear to me what's your intent. Your code right now draws transparent views, because you haven't applied any color to your `Box`. And as you're using a single item, `listState.firstVisibleItemIndex` will always be `0`, so your `isShow` should always be `true` right now.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Sorry to do not express my intent with the simple code.I was edited my question.The gragh is one of items in LazyColumn, and it has 200+ boxs. The ```LazyColumn``` get stuck  when the graph hides and shows,

Comment: I still wasn't been able to reproduce it with your updated code. Please edit it to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `LazyColumn`'s `items(...)` or `item { ..composable..}` to take advantage of its lazy-ness. For each item on your column, you need to surround it with `item` to tell compose that is a row inside that column.